# Linqdatasource and relational data problem

Tags: linq-to-sql, gridview, paging, linqdatasource

I have a problem with linqdatasource. I have gridview in my page and I set it's datasource to linqdatasource,also I set  AllowPaging="True" , AllowSorting="True".

```
<asp:GridView ID="cityGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
DataKeyNames="CityId" AllowPaging="True" 
AllowSorting="True" DataSourceID="LinqCityData">
```

Now in linqdatasource I want to retrieve data from two tables (relational tables with FK), there is no problem in this step.
I can use Select property of linqdatasource like this to select from other table

```
<asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqCityData" runat="server" 
ContextTypeName="ContactSysDataContext" 
TableName="Office_ContactSys_Cities" 
Select="new (CityId, CityName , Office_ContactSys_Province.ProvinceName)">
</asp:LinqDataSource>
```

or I cas use Selection event in linqdatasource

```
protected void LinqCityData_Selecting(object sender, LinqDataSourceSelectEventArgs e)
    {
        ContactSysDataContext db = new ContactSysDataContext();
        var CityResult= from p in db.Office_ContactSys_Cities join o in db.Office_ContactSys_Provinces on p.ProvinceId equals o.ProvinceId select new { o.ProvinceName, p.CityId, p.CityName };
        e.Result = CityResult;
    }
```

but after this step I can't use automatic delete in linqdatasource and instead I recieve this error:

> LinqDataSource 'LinqCityData' does not
>   support the Select property when the
>   Delete, Insert or Update operations
>   are enabled

Here is my question: How can I implement paging in gridview (of course for relational tables) using linqdatasource (linqdatasource with enabled delete or update)?

Answer (score 2):

If you remove the select statement from the linqdatasource, you will not get that error anymore.  And then you can use update, delete and insert.  Oh you'll also have to enable the delete insert and update in the datasource.

Here's an example:

```
<asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ContextTypeName="Custom.Data.DataAccessDataContext"

    TableName="CustomerSegmentMappings" 
    EnableDelete="True"
    EnableInsert="True"
    EnableUpdate="True">
</asp:LinqDataSource>
```